# Kubernetes pod stuck in pending state and no events

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

There aren't any other pods deployed. I have 2 nodes with zero pods. Its a `t3.small` instance type.

Is there any other commands to debug and see why it is still stuck in pending state?

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-6cc489dcd5-5jc8t   0/1     Pending   0          91s


kubectl describe pod mysql-6cc489dcd5-5jc8t
Name:           mysql-6cc489dcd5-5jc8t
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=mysql
                pod-template-hash=6cc489dcd5
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mysql-6cc489dcd5
Containers:
  mysql:
    Image:      mysql:5.6
    Port:       3306/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  dbpassword11
    Mounts:
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d from usermanagement-dbcreation-script (rw)
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-persistent-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nlx4p (ro)
Volumes:
  mysql-persistent-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  ebs-mysql-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  usermanagement-dbcreation-script:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      usermanagement-dbcreation-script
    Optional:  false
  default-token-nlx4p:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nlx4p
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Deployments shows that it has scaled and nothing wrong there.

```
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age    From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----   ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  5m34s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set mysql-6cc489dcd5 to 1
```

cat 01-storage-class.yml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc

provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

cat 02-persistent-volume-claim.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-mysql-pv-claim

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ebs-sc # Metadata name of the storage class
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

cat 03-UserManagement-ConfigMap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script

data:
  mysql_usermgt.sql: |-
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS usermgmt;
    CREATE DATABASE usermgt;
```

cat 04-mysql-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
   type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: mysql-deployment
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.6
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: dbpassword11
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage            # name from the volumes listed below
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script    # name from the volumes listed below
              mountPath:  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ebs-mysql-pv-claim
        - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
          configMap:
            name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
```

cat 05-mysql-clusterip-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql

spec:
  #type: # Defaults to cluster IP service
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306  # If name isn't provided, port can start as a list `- port: 3306`
      #targetPort # Defaults to containerPort
  clusterIP: None # Use POD IP directly
```

kubectl describe nodes

```
Name:               ip-192-168-14-238.ap-south-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=eksdemo1
                    alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=eksdemo1-ng-public1
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t2.small
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=eksdemo1-ng-public1
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-01cfab2ec59e55c25
                    eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId=lt-02527e7be817e66a5
                    eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1a
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-192-168-14-238.ap-south-1.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t2.small
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=ap-south-1a
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1a
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-0b3699bcac4e70d31"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:47 -0500
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-192-168-14-238.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:41:17 -0500
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:40 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:47 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:40 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:47 -0500   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:40 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:47 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:40 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:06:17 -0500   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   192.168.14.238
  ExternalIP:   15.206.94.127
  Hostname:     ip-192-168-14-238.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-192-168-14-238.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  ExternalDNS:  ec2-15-206-94-127.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         1
  ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      2039136Ki
  pods:                        11
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         940m
  ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      1551712Ki
  pods:                        11
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 10f1040dde9f47289c7e10ea3fb9f040
  System UUID:                EC2C067A-2E0E-8A49-76C1-7F5FFA16E7ED
  Boot ID:                    d2638886-d5b3-4fa6-a15b-e95e046397f5
  Kernel Version:             4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.6
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-south-1a/i-0b3699bcac4e70d31
Non-terminated Pods:          (5 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                   CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                   ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 aws-node-zn9v5                         10m (1%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 coredns-6b4cdc67b4-pzrl7               100m (10%)    0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (11%)    20h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-7bf8974dc8-cth9n    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-2vr6j                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-dd4wd                       100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests    Limits
  --------                    --------    ------
  cpu                         210m (22%)  0 (0%)
  memory                      70Mi (4%)   170Mi (11%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0
Events:                       <none>


Name:               ip-192-168-57-231.ap-south-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name=eksdemo1
                    alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name=eksdemo1-ng-public1
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t2.small
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    eks.amazonaws.com/capacityType=ON_DEMAND
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup=eksdemo1-ng-public1
                    eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup-image=ami-01cfab2ec59e55c25
                    eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateId=lt-02527e7be817e66a5
                    eks.amazonaws.com/sourceLaunchTemplateVersion=1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1b
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-192-168-57-231.ap-south-1.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t2.small
                    topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone=ap-south-1b
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-south-1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-south-1b
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"ebs.csi.aws.com":"i-0317d2c406ad6034d"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:49 -0500
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  ip-192-168-57-231.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:41:17 -0500
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:39 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:49 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:39 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:49 -0500   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:39 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:05:49 -0500   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Thu, 26 Nov 2020 01:40:39 -0500   Wed, 25 Nov 2020 05:06:20 -0500   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   192.168.57.231
  ExternalIP:   52.66.246.122
  Hostname:     ip-192-168-57-231.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  ip-192-168-57-231.ap-south-1.compute.internal
  ExternalDNS:  ec2-52-66-246-122.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         1
  ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      2039136Ki
  pods:                        11
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  39
  cpu:                         940m
  ephemeral-storage:           18242267924
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      1551712Ki
  pods:                        11
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 a14b97ab355f485294e0e6bd736775af
  System UUID:                EC2D6C5A-497D-E6A4-F235-CF3055FCB546
  Boot ID:                    c37c79e9-4bb1-4ffb-810f-80a4405cb403
  Kernel Version:             4.14.203-156.332.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.6
  Kubelet Version:            v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-south-1b/i-0317d2c406ad6034d
Non-terminated Pods:          (5 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                   CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                   ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 aws-node-qnjzl                         10m (1%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 coredns-6b4cdc67b4-whszf               100m (10%)    0 (0%)      70Mi (4%)        170Mi (11%)    20h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-controller-7bf8974dc8-cs6p8    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 ebs-csi-node-2qwjq                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-pkxc9                       100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         20h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests    Limits
  --------                    --------    ------
  cpu                         210m (22%)  0 (0%)
  memory                      70Mi (4%)   170Mi (11%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0
Events:                       <none>
```

Answer (score 4):

Is the AWS EBS volume attached to the instance? May a look in the console can help you out.
Also if can share kubectl get pvc,pv.

Answer (score 3):

In this setup, I would first suspect something wrong with the persistent storage. Do a describe on the Persistent Volume Claim and Storage Class to see whether they are alright.

Also, if this is an EKS cluster, you can use the preinstalled EBS storage class.

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

or

```
kubectl describe nodes
```

should give you some info about the nodes in your cluster. It could perhaps be a resource issue. I don't see any limits or requests around CPU/memory in your podspec. I'd try adding some and ensure that the minimum recommended value falls in line with what is available on your node.

Comment: I've added the output of `describe nodes`. I don't see any 100% resource used. Can you check the output?

Comment: I forgot I had some pods on name space kube-system. But I'm not sure how to find the issue with `describe nodes`. I'm about delete the cluster and recreate it with medium instance type.

Comment: can you do a kubectl get pv? or kubectl get pvc? could also be related to assigning storage

Answer (score 1):

In my case for some reason my cluster had been set to be cordoned which means no nodes could be scheduled. In minikube running `kubectl uncordon minikube` solved my problem of pods being stuck in pending. I figured this out by running `kubectl get nodes` and noticed the status said it could not schedule.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the standard reason (resource limits , tolerations, volumes and a like) another possible root cause: the deployment uses non default scheduler. look up for `schedulerName` field and its value . when a deployment/sts uses some custom scheduler it might not honor the K8s event logging mechanism.
In managed clusters you don't always have read access to the kube-system scheduler logs .

usually `kubectl get event -n [namespace of the problematic pod]` should include the scheduler logs. kubectl describe pod will also emit that info in the end.

Comment: `kubectl get event -n [my namespace]` was a very helpful command that still showed events even though the pod I'm inspecting had `Events:   <none>` in `kubectl describe job` output

Answer (score 0):

> Is the AWS EBS volume attached to the instance? May a look in the
> console can help you out. Also if can share kubectl get pvc,pv.

To add to this... Looks like you are on EKS, if you are using AWS EBS you will need to install the [Amazon EBS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html) to be able to use AWS EBS for persistentVolumes.